# Every character of a diagonalizable algebraic subgroup is a weight of a representation.

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group containing a diagonalizable closed subgroup $T$.

I want to show, that every character of $T$ is a weight of at least one representation of $G$. Can someone help?

Comment: I think you can just apply induction can't you? A character $\chi$ of $T$ defines a one-dimensional representation $k_\chi$ on the base field, induce to $G$. You should be able to find $\chi$ as a weight again in the induction.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me! (sorry for my late answer)